# Service is already enabled, and is dead

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following states:

```
copy_over_systemd_service_files:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/systemd/system/consul-template.service
    - source: salt://mesos/files/consul-template.service
    - owner: consul

start_up_consul-template_service:
  service.running:
    - name: consul-template
    - enable: True
    - restart: True
    - require:
      - file: copy_over_systemd_service_files
    - watch:
      - /etc/systemd/system/consul-template.service
```

when I run my state file I get the following error:

```
ID: start_up_consul-template_service
Function: service.running
    Name: consul-template
  Result: False
 Comment: Service consul-template is already enabled, and is dead
 Started: 17:27:38.346659
Duration: 2835.888 ms
 Changes:
```

I'm not sure what this means. All I want to do is restart the service once it's been copied over and I've done this before without issue. Looking back through the stack trace just shows that Salt ran `systemctl is-enabled consult-template`

Answer (score 1):

I think I was over complicating things. Instead I'm doing this:

```
consul-template:
  service.running:
    - require:
      - file: copy_over_systemd_service_files
    - watch:
      - /etc/systemd/system/consul-template.service
```